# formatting in python logging

Tags: python-3.x, logging, formatting

I'm new to programming in Python and now i have made a script to move files from one location to another.
Now i wanted to have a logfile for it, but i can't find a way to farmat the text it puts in the logfile.
I have the following code:

```
#logging
log= 'Succesfully moved', x, 'to', moveto
logging.basicConfig(filename='\\\\fatboy.leleu.be\\iedereen\\Glenn\\insitecopy.log',filemode='a',level=logging.INFO,format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',datefmt='%d/%m/%Y '   ' %I:%M:%S %p')
logging.info(log)
```

The output is this:

```
14/12/2018  08:54:17 AM ('Succesfully moved', '2126756_landrover.pdf', 'to', '\\\\fatboy.leleu.be\\MPWorkflow\\Jobs\\2126756_test\\PDF Druk')
14/12/2018  08:54:17 AM ('Succesfully moved', '2126757_landrover - kopie.pdf', 'to', '\\\\fatboy.leleu.be\\MPWorkflow\\Jobs\\2126757_test2\\PDF Druk')
```

Now i want to remove the brackets, the apostrophe and the comma, but don't know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `logging.info(" ".join(log))`, because your "log" variable looks if it was a tuple. But it will working only if log is really a tuple and contains only str type elements.
Python shows tuples in that form as you can see in your log: opening round bracket, items (between apostrophes if item is a string), closing round bracket.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out! It works perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

Pls, try code below;

```
log= 'Succesfully moved ' + x + ' to ' + moveto
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
log= 'Succesfully moved', x, 'to', moveto
```

Is creating a tuple try something like

```
log = 'Succefully moved {} to {}'.format(x, moveto)
```